# how can i make a dbus connection from a sandbox to pipewire

Tags: fedora, selinux, d-bus, sandbox

How can i create a DBUS connection to PipeWire (to communicate with the sound daemon) from a SElinux sandbox?

Answer (score 1):

Pipewire is usually run as a *user session service*, so you might want the *session DBus*, which is accessed through a Unix socket at `/run/user/<UID number>/bus`. The same directory will also contain Pipewire's own socket, in case you'll need to communicate directly with it.

If you have configured Pipewire to run as a *system service* instead, or otherwise need the *system DBus*, its socket is at `/run/dbus/system_bus_socket`.

If you are working with a custom SELinux sandbox, configure it to allow access to the appropriate socket and your sandboxed application will have access to the DBus.

SELinux restrictions are usually more or less tailored to the application, so without knowing more details it will be difficult to give specific advice. Many pre-built sandbox configurations include *SELinux booleans*: easy ON/OFF-type settings that can allow specific things if required by a particular use case of the application. Documentation on these can usually be found on a `<application name>_selinux` man page, if you have the `selinux-policy-doc` package installed. The booleans can be queried/manipulated with the `getsebool`/`setsebool` commands, or with the options of the `semanage boolean` command.